# How to access an element of a dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in a page called firstpagemidle.php,

```
DIV id="news" data-pageNum_rsnews="1" data-totalRows_rsnews="9" class="new">
```

And I load this page in another page by this code:

```
$('#bigmidlecontent').load("../"+tab+"/"+stab+"midle.php",'',loadboth);
```

And now I want to access the variable PageNum from the page that is already loaded. How can I do that?

Comment: you want to access a javascript variable that is defined in `another page` from `firstpagemidle.php` ?

Comment: what variable do you mean? a JS variable? a PHP variable?

Comment: I want to access pagenUm_rsnews ( from firstpagemidle.php) after this page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do that in the callback function you're referencing, as the elements would be loaded then

```
$('#bigmidlecontent').load("../"+tab+"/"+stab+"midle.php",'',loadboth);

function loadboth() {
    var pagenum = $('#news').data('pageNum_rsnews'); // 1
}
```

Comment: I use this function as follow
    function loadboth() {
    var pagenum = $('#new').data('pageNum_rsnews'); // 1
    alert(pagenum);
    }
but it alerts undefined

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, are you sure you have the right ID, and that the ID is unique, you can't use an ID more than once etc

Answer (score 1):

I use the function loadboth() exactly the same way as friends mentioned, but it didn't work.

After that I change the ID pagenum_rsnews to (pagenum) and now it works.

Comment: Who is *"friends"*?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery apparently converts data to lower case:

```
$('#bigmidlecontent').load("../" + tab + "/" + stab + "midle.php", '', loadboth);

function loadboth() {
    var pagenum = $('#news').data('pagenum_rsnews'); // 1
}
```

For extracting all data, use:

```
$('#bigmidlecontent').load("../" + tab + "/" + stab + "midle.php", '', loadboth);

function loadboth() {
    var pagenum = $('#news').data(); // {totalrows_rsnews: 9, pagenum_rsnews: 1}
}
```